# pastespecial causing macro to fail on one computer, but not any others

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I wrote a program to copy data from a third party program and paste it to an excel sheet at my work. Everything works perfectly on 4 out of the 5 computers I have run the macro on. However this last computer produces the

Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of range class failed.

The last time I ran into this error it was because I was using Cell.Activate in the script. I have since re-wrote it to avoid using this, but the one computer is still having issues. Why could this be?

The program basically switches windows to a third party program that only accepts keyboard entry as input. I use sendkeys to get to the data I need and then copy it and paste it over to excel where I can work with the data.

I dim and set the RQWB much earlier in the program, but here is the lines for that.

```
Dim RQWB As Workbook
Set RQWB = Workbooks("Excel workbook")
```

Here is the surrounding for loop.

```
            'find missing emails
For count3 = 0 To 200
    If IsEmpty(RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -3).Value) = True Then

    Else

        RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -3).Copy

        AppActivate "Other program"
        Sleep 500
        SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True 
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "1", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True 
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "2", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True 
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "1", True
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "~", True 
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "c ", True 
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "^v", True 
        Sleep 70
        SendKeys "^x", True 
        Sleep 70            
        SendKeys "^a", True 
        Sleep 70            
        SendKeys "^c", True 
        Sleep 70
        RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Delete
        RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Sleep 500
        If RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A24").Value = "CONDITION" Then
            RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            AppActivate "OTHER PROGRAM"
            Sleep 500
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 70
        ElseIf RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A24").Value = "CONDITION" Then
            RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("D24").Value = "=LEFT(A6, 6)"
            RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("D24").Copy
            AppActivate "OTHER PROGRAM"
            Sleep 500
            SendKeys "^v", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "30", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "^x", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "^a", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "^c", True
            Sleep 70
            RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Delete
            RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            If RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A8").Value = "CONDITION" Then
                Sleep 70
                AppActivate "OTHER PROGRAM"
                Sleep 500
                SendKeys ("3")
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys ("~")
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys "^x", True
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys "^a", True
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys "^c", True
                Sleep 70
                RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Delete
                RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
                Sleep 70
                If IsEmpty(RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A21").Value) = True Then
                    RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
                Else
                    RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A21").Value
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").Value = "===============================================================================" Then
            AppActivate "OTHER PROGRAM"
            Sleep 500
            SendKeys "30", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "^x", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "^a", True
            Sleep 70
            SendKeys "^c", True
            Sleep 70
            RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Delete
            RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            Sleep 500
            If RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A8").Value = "CONDITION" Then
                Sleep 70
                AppActivate "OTHER PROGRAM"
                Sleep 500
                SendKeys ("3")
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys ("~")
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys "^x", True
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys "^a", True
                Sleep 70
                SendKeys "^c", True
                Sleep 70
                RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Delete
                RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
                Sleep 70
                If IsEmpty(RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A21").Value) = True Then
                    RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
                Else
                    RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A21").Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next count3
```

I am running this script with the workbook hidden so I needed to add RQWB to tell excel where to paste without .activate.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Sorry for leaving the code out. It is a work related program so I was not sure how much of it I should post. also it's kinda long and I don't know how much is relevant. but here is some more code. If you still need more I can post the whole thing I would just need to edit out the sensitive bits.

Comment: More code = more clues

Comment: As Tim wrote, how do you expect us to help ??? where is `RQWB` defined and set ? post the rest of your relevant code

Comment: Edited. Added more code and a little more explanation.

Comment: *Which line* does it error on?

Comment: `RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial` @tim williams

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error comes from this line:

```
RQWB.Worksheets("Email_List").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -3).Copy
```

Could you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: With this line I copy an account number and use it in the other program to open their account. once the `sendkeys` get to "^x, ^A, ^C"  I am copying the screen of the other program and then `RQWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial` is supposed to paste that screen on to excel.

Comment: no I mean, that the line I posted gives me an error when I try that with my Excel